# import wavemaker statement cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I am taking over code someone else wrote and am having to find everything they used for this project manually because they didn't send everything that was needed. (One of those out of the country contract work deals.) Anyway, I'm having trouble finding something. They imported com.wavemaker.runtime.data, com.wavemaker.runtime.services and com.wavemaker.json.type and I can't figure out how to get these unresolved errors to go away. I've moved WaveMaker into the same folder as my project and I've searched high and low for a .jar file on my machine and on the internet to no avail. Please help?? (FYI I'm using Eclipse & Java)

Comment: Have you looked at http://wavemaker.com ?

Comment: Yes I have. I don't see anything that can help.

Comment: Did you download and install the Wavemaker product? It looks like those libraries are included there.

Comment: Yes I have, and like I said I moved all of the product into the same folder as the code, and that didn't help.

Comment: Would importing the java project into wavemaker help?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, you have to add the jars to the eclipse configuration path (i.e: ~/WaveMaker/projects/wm_example_project/lib), when you find it, make sure that you add all those libs to your build path.